# Min values for segments of columns of csv data when another column has same value using numpy

Tags: arrays, csv, numpy

So I have csv data with roughly a total of 9 columns. I specifically want to look at
4 of those 9 columns (first, 2nd, 4th, and 8th) and use the first and 2nd to determine which rows out of those columns to return.

So my data looks something like this (a few lines)

```
col 1     col 2       col 4    col 8
0         -4          19       21
0         5           16       18
1         5           17       3 
1         7           5        4
1         9           6        5
2         0           13       7  
3         12          14       6
3         -12         7        8
```

What I want to do is for each unique value in col 1 (0, 1,2,3, etc. . . .) I want to view col 2 and find the minimum value (I also have to do this for max, but similar idea) within that column, and return that row that has the minimum number in col 2 for each number in col 1.

up until now all I've got is:

```
    data = np.loadtxt(filenm, skiprows = 1, dtype = float, delimiter = ',')
    unique = np.unique(data[:,0])
```

I'm pretty much clueless what to do at this point. I've tried to search up each unique value in col 1 but I dont know how to do that based on values for each in col2. I know ways to get this done on panda but I'm specifically trying to do something using numpy

Comment: "I know ways to get this done on panda but I'm specifically trying to do something using numpy".  Speaking as someone who's used `numpy` pretty much every working day for years: why?

Comment: Perhaps because I'm trying out different methods and it's part of an assignment I'm sorting out for other people that I need to get done. It's basically a way of try to learn numpy to do this stuff and not other methods, the end goal is to learn the stuff, the actual data itself is just part of an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is an equivalent `numpy` function for `pandas.DataFrame.grouby`, but you could try something like this

```
unq = np.unique(data[:, 0]).tolist()
mins = []

for val in unq:
    mask = data[:, 0] == val
    mins.append((val, data[:, 1][mask].min()))
```

Or you could use `itertools.groupby` ... it's less readable, but more fun.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

grp = groupby(enumerate(data[:, 1].tolist()), key=lambda x : data[:, 0][x[0]])
mins = [(i, min(group, key=itemgetter(1))[1]) for i, group in grp]
```

In either case, `mins` will be

```
[(0.0, -4.0), (1.0, 5.0), (2.0, 0.0), (3.0, -12.0)]
```

**NOTE:**
If you use `itertools.groupby` you have to sort by the column you're gouping by first.

**EDIT:**

Getting the entire row containing the minimum value in column 2 for each group is similar

```
unq = np.unique(data[:, 0]).tolist()
mins = []

for val in unq:
    mask = data[:, 0] == val
    i = data[mask][:, 1].argmin()
    mins.append((val, data[mask][i, 1:]))
```

And using `itertools`

```
grp = groupby(enumerate(data[:, 1].tolist()), key=lambda x : data[:, 0][x[0]])
mins = [(i, data[min(group, key=itemgetter(1))[0], 1:]) for i, group in grp]
```

Using either method `mins` will be

```
[(0.0, array([ -4.,  19.,  21.])),
 (1.0, array([  5.,  17.,   3.])),
 (2.0, array([  0.,  13.,   7.])),
 (3.0, array([-12.,   7.,   8.]))]
```

Comment: So I tried this, but the one problem is that it's only appending the column 1 stuff with the column 2 stuff but not also the column 3 and 4 stuff that I need based on the column one stuff I selected.